# Packing a number of unequal circles in a rectangle

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, set-covering, packing

Given the dimension of a rectangle and the radii of n unequal circles, how can I decide if these circles can fit in the rectangle?

I don't know if there is a formula to compute such a thing!

The formula is straightforward if they are only two circles, not n circles. Also, it can be deducted if they are rectangles, not circles. But I can't figure it out for that case.

Comment: This is NP-hard, as well as for rectangles, you're unlikely going to find any formula

Comment: If the circles all have distinct diameters, then you just have to check that the largest's circle diameter is less than the rectangle's width, and place all circles around the same centre.

Comment: @stef For circle packing, each pair of circles must have disjoint interiors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can determine whether such a packing is possible by solving a nonconvex quadratically constrained feasibility problem where the decision variables are the coordinates of the circle centers.  See http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/05/knapsack-packing-difficult-miqcp.html

Comment: And here is a state-of-the-art heuristic https://doi.org/10.1007/s11590-013-0646-1